# How to compile strace for ARM Linux?

Tags: github, gcc, makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I saw this project https://github.com/strace/strace. (is that the best project for strace?)

And I have gcc cross compiler for Arm Linux.

How can I compile it for Arm Linux?

I look here https://github.com/strace/strace/tree/master/linux/arm but I didn't find Make file

Comment: The specifics will depend on a) your particular Linux, b) your particular toolchain, and c) your strace source.  Take a look at this article: it should get you pointed in the right direction: http://jensd.be/800/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-with-ubuntu-16-04-lts.  See also: https://strace.io/

Comment: From the `strace/strace` directory, check it out from git, run `./bootstrap` and `./configure`, then make.

Comment: Or, per the [README](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/README-configure), `./configure && make && make install'`.  The important thing is to read the README ;) Keystone: please let us know how it goes.

Comment: The README is a good resource - thanks for pointing it out -  but isn't quite complete. The git repo doesn't have a ./configure file; it needs to be generated with ./bootstrap. This is alluded to in the [INSTALL](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/INSTALL-git.md) file. I have built strace this way.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics for building strace from source will depend on:

a) your particular Linux,

b) your particular toolchain, and

c) your strace source.

Take a look at this article: it should get you pointed in the right direction:

[Cross compiling for ARM with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://jensd.be/800/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-with-ubuntu-16-04-lts).

See also https://strace.io/.  It points to exactly the same the GitHub source tree you cited: https://github.com/strace/strace.  It also gives you detailed information, and links to mailing list sand an IRC channel for additional help.

Finally:

> Be sure to read the README* file(s)!

Usually the first thing you need to do is run `./configure`. This generates a Makefile which is tailored to your configuration